# Is there a way to fold diffs in github pull request file view

Tags: github

I have made 5 modifications. The third modification is adding a very long file which doesn't need close inspection. I'd like to fold file 3 so I can see the small but important diffs of files 1, 2, 4, and 5 without doing tons of scrolling past file 3. I can't find such a button on github's PR page, even though such a thing exists on Phab.

Am I missing it or is it not there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sent a feature request. Reply from github:

> Indeed, that's not possible currently. I do agree that would be useful, so I'll pass your suggestion to the team working on diffs to consider, but I can't make any promises.

Update: they added the feature

Comment: Is there any way I can +1 your request?

Comment: I think that you can send another request asking for the same thing and that might bump the feature up on their priority list internally. 
https://github.com/contact

Answer (score 0):

You can check my chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-code-tree/caffoilocbbhnkdlpdcfanpbeholjdii

It helps me a bit for checking commits or pr's :)